# Limit Superior And Limit Inferior with sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Use the definition to calculate the limit superior and the limit inferior of the sequence $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(n)=2+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

I'm confused by what definition this means. Should I use $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to show an interval that this is true?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\sup\limits_{k\geq n} f(k) = 2 +\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\inf\limits_{k\geq n} f(k) = 2 -\frac{1}{n}$$
By definition, we have that
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sup\limits_{k\geq n} f(k)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \inf\limits_{k\geq n} f(k)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(2-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
You can show that these two limits are 2 by the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence tends to $2$. So you have
$$\limsup f(n) = \liminf f(n) = \lim f(n) =2$$

Comment: But wouldnt I have to justify that?

Comment: Like by proving that the sequence is going to converge?

Comment: Of course, you have to justifiy all that is not clear to you ! So indeed, first explain why your sequence converges ; then prove that in this case, $\liminf = \limsup = \lim$.

Comment: is this  a valid proof?

Comment: Who is $x$ ? who is $\epsilon$ ? who is $n$ ?... it's unreadable !